# How do I properly copy BIN_logs to a another mysql server for testing an "undo"?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

About a week ago a user, meaning to delete one category from an app database, deleted all/most of them thru the web app that runs the database. I thought we did not have backups so we revived an old server that had been decommissioned about a year ago and got the data from that table and injected it into the table on the current system. This worked ... ok. A few errors from not having some categories that apparently created after migrating from old server to new server. Today I find the binary logs. I did not think there were any but

`"mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;"`

and

`"mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;"`

show that we have active bin logs. I have never done anything with bin logs but I'm hoping to use them to undo this mess. I am not sure how do this. I would like to copy the bin logs to a test server where I already have a copy of the database running. Do I just scp bin_log username@testserver:/ or is there some util I need to use? Any and all help is appreciated. Also, if you know of any awesome "How-to's" on doing this, please link them in. Both new and old server are running MySQL 5.0.51b. The new test server is running MariaDB 5.5.60. New server is running RHEL 6.10 and test server is running RHEL 7.6. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: "Thou shall not loose data" is the number 1 rule of a DBA.

Comment: Ok, you got me. I've been a bad DBA, well, sysop really ... tho, I am not the one who deleted it. But does noone know how to recover from binary logs?  :(